# Not able to show joined table data in my Angaular 6 view with material data table

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs

I need your help about angular with firebase. I want to get records from 2 nodes something like join.

Nodes are like that -

1- users { key, username, usertype_key}

2- user_types {key(which is exists in users table named "usertype_key"), user_type}

I need to make join with both table and get records like that
{users.key, users.username, user_types.user_type}

I wrote the code like that -

// My user services code user.service.ts

```
        getUsersList() {
            const ref = firebase.database().ref();
            const userRef = ref.child('/users');
            const utypeRef = ref.child('/user_types');
            const resp = [];
            userRef.on('child_added', snapnotes => {
            utypeRef.child(snapnotes.val().user_type).once('value', subsnap => {
        resp.push({
        'key': snapnotes.key,
        'username': snapnotes.val().username,
        'user_type': subsnap.val().user_type
        });
    });
});
return resp;
```

}

// My user component code is like that user.component.ts

```
         constructor(private userService: UserService,
           private authService: AuthService,
           private matDialog: MatDialog) {
         }

        async ngOnInit() {
         this.userSubscribe = await this.authService.user$.subscribe(user => this.userId = user.uid);
         // here I am getting users list
         this.items =  new MatTableDataSource(this.userService.getUsersList());
         }
```

my issues

1- how do convert datasnapshot to a observable so I can subscribe it on my component code

2- not able to initialize material data table.

Is there any other way to do it with out affecting optimization speed.

Thanks and regards
Rajan Bhadauria

Comment: please use the angular tag for the new angular 2+ as angularjs tag is for angular 1.x